# One norm is stronger than but not equivalent to another norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=C^{1}([0,1])$. For $x \in X$, let $$||x||_{0}^{'}=|x(0)|+||x'||_{\infty}$$

I need to show that $||.||_{0}^{'}$ is stronger than but not equivalent $||.||_{\infty}$.

It is easy to see that $||.||_{0}^{'}$ is stronger as for any $t \in (0,1]$, $$x(t)=tx'(\alpha)+x(0) \implies |x(t)| \le |x'(\alpha)|+|x(0)|$$
where $\alpha \in (0,t)$ 
$$\implies |x(t)| \le ||x'||_{\infty}+|x(0)|=||x||_{0}^{'}$$
Since this happens for all $t$, we have 
 $$||x||_{0}^{'}\ge ||x||_{\infty}$$

For the other part, I proceed by contradiction. Suppose they are equivalent. Then there exists a $k \gt 0$ such that $$||x||_{0}^{'} \le k ||x||_{\infty}$$
Then for $x_c(t)=cx^2+d$, $||x_c||_{0}^{'}=|d|+2|c|$, where as $||x_c||_{\infty}=d+c$, where $c \gt 0$
Then for such a fixed $k$ and a fixed $c$ we can find a $d$ such that $k(d+c) \lt |d|+2c  $. This would lead us to a contradiction.

Is this right??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: $x_c(t) = ct^2+d$ does not work here. It is handled by $k=2$. But what about $x_n(t) = t^n$?

Comment: Try $x_n(t)=\sin(nt)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt does not work since it lies in a two dimensional vector space, hence all the norm are equivalent. This is the "deep" reason for which it cannot work. As pointed out by Zardo, the choice $k=2$ does the job.

The construction of a counter-example rests on the following fact: a smooth bounded function can oscillate very quickly between its bounds. In such a way, the infinite norm is fixed, but that of the derivative may be big. this lead to Zardo's example $x_n(t):=t^n$.